python in snowflake - UDF with aggregation seemingly not working
I am trying to do some aggregations with pandas df groupby/transform inside UDF, using python with snowflake. I come across incorrect results - when I do aggregations outside of UDF, all works well, but it does not work when executed inside the function body.
Let's register simple UDF for demonstration:
create or replace function some_sum(col1 int, col2 varchar)
returns int
language python
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.9
packages = ('pandas')
handler = 'some_sum'
as $$
import pandas as pd
from _snowflake import vectorized

@vectorized(input=pd.DataFrame)
def some_sum(input_df):
    input_df.columns = ['A', 'B']
    input_df['C'] = input_df.groupby(['B'])['A'].transform('sum')
    return input_df['C']
$$

Now here's what I try to execute:
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, call_udf
import pandas as pd

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    some_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'B' : ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']})
    some_df = session.create_dataframe(some_df)
    result_df = some_df.with_column('teh_sum', call_udf('some_sum', some_df['A'], some_df['B']))
    result_df.show()
    return result_df

When executed in Snowflake Worksheet, here's what is seen in "Results" in web GUI - like no aggregation happened in 'teh_sum' column



A
B
TEH_SUM




1
c
1


2
c
2


3
c
3


4
d
4


5
d
5


6
d
6


7
e
7


8
e
8


9
e
9


10
e
10



However, in "PY Output" tab in web GUI, I see correct results:



A
B
TEH_SUM




1
c
6


2
c
6


3
c
6


4
d
15


5
d
15


6
d
15


7
e
34


8
e
34


9
e
34


10
e
34



Does anybody know why this inconsistency and error in "Results" tab? Especially that I would like to materialize results of such aggregation as a table, and then what I get as table is "Results" tab i.e. incorrect rows.
When I do the same aggregation but without UDF call, the results are OK:
some_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'B' : ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']})
some_df['teh_sum'] = some_df.groupby(['B'])['A'].transform('sum')
result_df = session.create_dataframe(some_df)
return result_df

Sorry for mistakes, if there are any, I am quite new to all this.

Something very wrong with Snowflake Dataframe. I see the same results.

Based on the query history snowflake is running below SQL for result_df = some_df.with_column('the_sum', call_udf('test.public.some_sum', some_df['A'], some_df['B'])) operation
SELECT "A", "B", test.public.some_sum("A", "B") AS "THE_SUM" FROM "TEST"."PUBLIC"."SNOWPARK_TEMP_TABLE_54NO971VY9" LIMIT 10;
I tried running the SQL UDF call instead of dataframe UDF call. It works fine


I also noticed that calling this UDF as SQL function works well. It looks like this is simply an issue with Snowflake Dataframe and there is not much I can do to fix it except for reporting it as bug?

Yes, that’s the only way to get the eyes of Snowflake.
